# Система слота в JavaScript, проблема с if else

Tags: javascript, сравнение

Я сделаю что-то типа слот аппарата, все у меня работает кроме одного. У меня аппарат показывает выигрыш, когда рядом будут 3 одинаковые картинки. Я хочу еще сделать так, когда например попадут 3 семерки тогда размер выигрыша был другой, когда попадут 3 вишни, размер выигрыша был другим. Как можно это реализовать ? В `if else` не понимаю как это написать.

Это у меня определяет выигрыш:

```js
if (pic.src == pic2.src && pic2.src == pic3.src) {
        win.innerHTML = '1000';
    } else if (pic4.src == pic5.src && pic5.src == pic6.src) {
        win.innerHTML = '1000';
    } else if (pic7.src == pic8.src && pic8.src == pic9.src) {
        win.innerHTML = '1000';
    } else {
        winner.innerHTML = '0';
    }
```

Comment: `pic.src == pic.src` - ??

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос

Comment: а если `pic2.src == pic3.src == pic4.src`?

Comment: Для чего ?) у меня на каждой линии 3 элементы pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делать вообще без else if (хотя конечный результат не поменяется)

```
/* Объект коэффициентов. Ключи — адреса картинок */
let coefs = {
  "strawberry.png": 1.5,
  "banana.png": 0.8,
  "seven.png": 2,
  "cherry.png": 1.5,
};

let current; /* Адрес выигравшей картинки */
let sum = 0;

updateSumByPics(pic1, pic2, pic3);
updateSumByPics(pic4, pic5, pic6);
updateSumByPics(pic7, pic8, pic9);

winner.textContent = sum;

function updateSumByPics(pic1, pic2, pic3){
  if( pic1.src == pic2.src && pic2.src == pic3.src ){ 
    current = pic1.src;
    sum = 1000 * coefs[current];
    /* Из объекта coefs достается число, в зависимости от значения current = pic1.src 
       и домножается на 1000 */
  }
}
```

P.s. http://learn.javascript.ru/ — 4-й и 5-й пункты, Объекты и массивы.

Answer (score 1):

```
var picture = "nopicture";
if (pic.src == pic2.src && pic2.src == pic3.src) {
  picture = pic.src;
} else if (pic4.src == pic5.src && pic5.src == pic6.src) {
  picture = pic4.src;
} else if (pic7.src == pic8.src && pic8.src == pic9.src) {
  picture = pic7.src;
}

var prizes = {};
prizes["nopicture"] = 0;
prizes["cherry.jpg"] = 1000;
prizes["seven.jpg"] = 2000;

win.innerHTML = prizes[picture];
```

Comment: Я не понял что сделает данный код,